# Coloring multiple columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to color every other column in my excel file, the excel file has 500 columns. I came up with a macro which colors 5 columns at a time. Is there a way I can color all the columns at once.Here is my code. I am looking for a code that colors all the columns and I do not have to do it manually.

```
 Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A19").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1:A19").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1:A19").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1:A19").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the Columns collection of the worksheet, and then for each Column, the 'column' property is the Column Index.  Check that to see if it is even or odd, and set the colour.

```
Public Sub Colour()
Dim Column As Range
For Each Column In ActiveSheet.Columns
    If Column.Column Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Column.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next Column
End Sub
```

To limit the columns, or change the how many are ordered, you can use a "for" loop instead of a For Each loop.  Eg:

```
Public Sub Colour()
Dim colIndex As Long
For colIndex = 1 To ActiveSheet.Columns.Count Step 3    '//Step 3 means every third column.
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colIndex).Interior.Color = vbRed
Next colIndex
End Sub
```

if you wanted to limit it to 500 columns:

```
Public Sub Colour()
Dim colIndex As Long
For colIndex = 1 To 500 Step 3    '//Step 3 means every third column.
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colIndex).Interior.Color = vbRed
Next colIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you the code works perfectly. However, is there a way to limit the number of columns I want to color? Also what shall I do if I want to leave two columns between every colored column. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sure - a `for` loop with `step` is easier in that case.  See updated code above.